# how write in script bash: su - user, command, password, without ask me password?

Tags: bash, passwords, su

i will create file sh (bash script)

```
#!/bin/bash
su - username -c XXXXXXXX
```

xxxxxx= command

where i put my password?( but NOT ask me password in terminal..how?)

Comment: Putting your root password in a script is a **very** bad idea.  `sudo su` might be a better solution. (And sudo can be configured to work passwordless for certain commands).

Comment: it's not dangerous because it's for me my home, not in remote or in server..

Answer (score 1):

You should look into properly setting up your `sudoers` file.  You would do this with a program called `visudo`, which does some behind-the-scenes magic.

`sudoers` can be set up in a way such that any user can be given access to a limited set or all commands available on the system.  You can also set it up so that a user can run any command as another user.  I think this third method is the way you'll decide to go.

However, If you've decided this is something you truly want to accomplish, I would recommend determining what commands you want to run, and use the whitelist approach, vs unlocking all commands.

**If you're running Chromium, or Firefox, or any server/client exposed to the Internet as a user in the sudoers file with unfettered, password-less access, you might as well be running them under root.**

1. `visudo`
2. Add the following entry

   - user1    ALL=(user2) NOPASSWD: /bin/bash

---

```
user1@host $ sudo -u user2 cat /home/user2/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Resources:

1. [allow sudo to another user without password](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/82527)
2. [visudo man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/visudo)
3. [Ubuntu's Sudoers Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers)

Comment: sorry i dont understand, i try to understand: #!/bin/bash
visudo username ALL=(user2) NOPASSWD: /bin/bash  user1@host $ sudo -u user2 echo "banana"     this is right or i'm wrong?

Comment: Don't blindly do this.  Read, read read.  If you do this wrong, you can cause severe issues or introduce vulnerabilities.  Read about `visudo`.  Read about `sudoers`.